# Data processing in the cloud with Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have build a Windows Phone app. I send data to a database in Azure. I need this data to be processed and the results to be send back to the user, so the app remains 'light'.
Sorry if the question is a bit general, but what service should I use to process data in the cloud?

Comment: How about a Mobile Service? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

Comment: @l19 I have used that to save user's data to a database, but I don't know what to do next. I want to do some calculations based on these data and then give feedback to the user.

Comment: Push notifications: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-push/